# Issue with Renderman and Blender 2.75

Tags: add-on, renderman-render-engine

Earlier today, I was able to enable Pixar's Renderman add-on for Blender 2.71. I then decided to update to Blender 2.75, but when I tried re-enabling Renderman, I got this message:[image: Error message]

Anyone know why?

Comment: Are your Blender and Renderman version based on the same CPU architecture? Is Renderman folder under C:\Program Files\Pixar\RenderManProServer-20.0\ ?

Comment: Yes to both. I've noticed that I'm also unable to enable the network renderer and renderfarm.fi

Comment: I presume you have RenderMan itself installed, not just the addon?

Comment: Yes, it was working fine with Blender 2.71

Comment: Have you asked / searched on the [PRMan github page](https://github.com/bsavery/PRMan-for-Blender/issues), the author of the add-on is still very active and responds to questions promptly.

Comment: Please provide System Info.

Comment: Renderman module is missing, so I'd suggest moving to the renderman binaries folder and install it again - this should work.

Comment: Posted this to Github a couple of hours ago, still in the process of trying to figure this out. I'm running the 64 bit version of Windows 8.1

@poor What module do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but when I updated renderman 19 to 20, my problem was solved.